# CSS: How to pin/fix elements relative to the background?

Tags: html, css, twine

I make quest using twine.
I need all the elements to behave as a single solid object when changing the screen size.
Now their positions are independent of each other.

In Twine I can manage all objects through the tw-story (like .body)
or use tw-passage for description(black on attached gif) and tw-link for answers(grey on gif)

```
tw-story
{
    background-image: url(../Images/TavernQuest/defentures_quest_back.png);
    background-size: cover;

    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 11% 19%;
    object-fit: cover;

} 

tw-passage {
    color: black;
    max-width: 50%;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
}

tw-link
{
   object-fit: cover;
   font-size: 1.8vw;

   color: grey;
}
```

How to make element position pin on background during window size change?

This is link to imgur gif that shows problem 
https://i.imgur.com/5IWS7rq.gifv

Comment: Can you add your html code?

Comment: `background-size: contain` might help you. But just like @little_coder said, add some html here to understand where you are adding the background and where the texts are.

Comment: @little_coder I have only auto generated by Twine huge html code  https://www.dropbox.com/s/55kt7yyoryzypd6/Gnomes.html?dl=0

Comment: @Towkir contain will create pattern with background image https://i.imgur.com/tH9Pv63.png

Comment: @user3484857 So you want the background image to be responsive when resizing?

Comment: You can add `position: relative;` to the `tw-story` and add `position:absolute;` to `tw-passage` and then add value to top, left, right or bottom ot the tw-passage.

Comment: it's hard to help unless you add your `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add on your css code.

```
tw-story {
    background-image: url(yourimage);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 11% 19%;
    position: relative;
    object-fit: cover;
}

tw-passage {
    color: black;
    max-width: 50%;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; //change as desired
}
```